# Placeholder image in JViewport of JScrollPane for empty JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jviewport

I have a `JTable` and want my user to drag&drop entries into that JTable.

To make that as obvious as possible, I want to display a placeholder image like *"Please drag stuff HERE using your mouse!"* in the background of the table, as long as the table is still empty.

Therefore, I've set up a custom `JViewport` using `createViewport()` of `JScrollPane`. See the following snippet from my `JScrollPane`:

```
@Override
protected JViewport createViewport() {
    return new JViewport() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
            super.paintComponent( g );
            // XXX Draw background image here XXX
        }
    };
}
```

To simplify the snippet, I've replaced the *"draw a BufferedImage centered"* stuff with a comment as it's not relevant to the question.

So far, the approach seems to work fine.

But of course, the background image is permanent, even if I add entries to the JTable.

How would you make it disappear as soon as the first entry is added to the JTable?

- Add a `TableModelListener` that somehow triggers the viewport to `paintComponent` again?
- Or is there a way for the `JViewport` to detect changes in "its" displayed component (its JTable) and redraw the Viewport then? (Would avoid coupling the data model and the Viewport.)

Comment: Check if your model contains data and if so don't draw the image?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer Unfortunately, `paintComponent` of the `JViewPort` isn't invoked, when data is added. (And the JViewport has no direct access to the TableModel.) `paintComponent` is only invoked, for example, if I resize the JFrame but not for changes to the JTable. So I'm looking for an elegant way to update and redraw the viewport if data is added. I thought there might be some generic approach for JScrollPane as it can be used for components other than JTable as well.

Comment: I would solve it in a slightly different way - while there is no data in the table, display a different component, this could act as your “drop target” initially, once data is added, switch the views to your table

Comment: Better. Solves the coupling problem

Comment: If the paint method is not invoked when adding data, then simply invoke it yourself. An easy way to do this might be to simply extend the JViewPort and add the necessary code, for example, creating an `Boolean empty` variable within the JViewPort, then in your drag/drop event if data is added to the table for the first time just change that variable and make a call to repaint(). Then in the paint method just check the same variable and only print the background image if the variable is false.